# How to redirect all error messages to logger

Tags: python, logging

I want to capture all error messages and warnings that are triggered from a library (in my case pytorch_lightning) in a log file. My current setup only captures some of the warnings, but I would like to capture all the warnings/errors that PyTorch sends to stdout. How can I do this?

```py
import logging

# Config logger
logging.basicConfig(
  encoding='utf-8',
  level=logging.DEBUG,
  filename=log_path,)

# Redirect all warnings to log file
logging.captureWarnings(True)

# Redirect any error messages to log file???
# ....
# ....

# Pytorch code that will lead to warnings/errors that I
# want stored in the logger file
# ....
```

The above code will catch only warnings like the following:

> WARNING:py.warnings:C:\Users\jared\Anaconda3\envs\base-torch\lib\site-packages\torch\functional.py:445:
> UserWarning: torch.meshgrid: in an upcoming release, it will be
> required to pass the indexing argument. (Triggered internally at
> ..\aten\src\ATen\native\TensorShape.cpp:2157.)   return
> _VF.meshgrid(tensors, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]

but will **not** capture warnings like the following:

> WARNING: The shape inference of prim::Constant type is missing, so it
> may result in wrong shape inference for the exported graph. Please
> consider adding it in symbolic functio in symbolic function.